# How to create two nodes at a time?

Tags: nodes, 6

I have one cck content type and two fields in this content type 
**1. is First name** 
**2. is Last name** 
i am trying TODO when i fill this these fields and click on save button Automatically create **Forum topic** with the name of first name text box value.

 how it is possible ? plz help

i am using Drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easy with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Load and init the Drupal System
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
require_once 'modules/forum/forum.admin.inc';

function fourm_activities_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
my_debug($form_id);

  if($form_id == 'testing_forum_node_form')
  {
    global $base_url;
//      my_debug($form);
    //add function to complete to at the end of array

    if(arg(2) && arg(2)!= 'edit')
    {
        $form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][]='fourm_activities_form_id_submit_handler';
    }
  }
}
    function fourm_activities_form_id_submit_handler($form, &$form_state)

    {
        $name   =   $form['nid']['#post']['field_test'][0]['value'];

        $test_nid = $form_state['nid'];

        global $user;

        $newNode            = (object) NULL;
        $newNode->type      = 'forum';
        $newNode->title     = $name;
        $newNode->uid       = $user->uid;
        $newNode->created   = strtotime("now");
        $newNode->changed   = strtotime("now");
        $newNode->status    = 1;
        $newNode->comment   = 0;
        $newNode->promote   = 0;
        $newNode->moderate  = 0;
        $newNode->sticky    = 0;

        node_save($newNode);
        $final_nid =    $newNode->nid;

        $node = node_load($test_nid);
        $node->field_forum_reference[0]['nid'] = $final_nid;
        node_save($node);

        //$form_state['clicked_button']['#post']['field_forum_reference']['nid']['nid'] = $newNode->nid;

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what I'm seeing here. Why are you bootstrapping Drupal? Is this a stand-alone php script? In that case, it's not a real module and I don't see how your form_alter implementation could work like this. You may want to read some pages from the [Module Developers Guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).